# Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1. spring jdbc

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbc

Hi All I am using spring simple JDBC template to call oracle function

the function is as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION RADON_DBA.Dbf_Verify_Address_Wrapper(P_Addr1 VARCHAR2,
         P_Addr2 VARCHAR2,
         P_City VARCHAR2,
         P_State VARCHAR2,
         P_Zip_Code VARCHAR2,
         P_App_Identifier VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN

RETURN (radon_dba.Dbf_Verify_Address(radon_dba.address_t(P_Addr1,P_Addr2,P_City,P_State,P_Zip_Code,P_App_Identifier)));

END;
```

and my dao class is as below

```
    public Integer fetchVerifiedId(Address address, String vSource) {
   SimpleJdbcCall getVerifiedId =new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withCatalogName("RADON_DBA")
        .withFunctionName("Dbf_Verify_Address_Wrapper").withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess();
    SqlParameterSource parMap =new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("P_Addr1", address.getAddressLine1())
        .addValue("P_Addr2", address.getAddressLine2())
        .addValue("P_App_Identifier",vSource)
        .addValue("P_City",address.getCity())
        .addValue("P_State",address.getState())
        .addValue("P_Zip_Code",address.getZip());
        Integer verified_id = getVerifiedId.executeFunction(Integer.class, parMap); 
        return verified_id;
    }
```

when i execute i get the below error

```
Exception: CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{? = call RADON_DBA.DBF_VERIFY_ADDRESS_WRAPPER()}]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17041]; Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1.
```

Comment: You need to specify IN on the parameters in the PL/SQL function.

Comment: May be you want to call `addValue()` in the same order that the parameters are declared in the function definition?

Comment: could you please elaborate on that.i am new to spring jdbc

Comment: i changed the order of add value still getting the error

Comment: Try dropping withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess() call.

Comment: turns out it is the issue with ORACLE 11G driver http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/90051-problems-calling-oracle-stored-function-using-simplejdbccall

Comment: It got solved for me by specifying the schema also like this.
 SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource).withSchemaName("<schema name>").withCatalogName("<packagename>").withFunctionName("function name")